# Inhomogeneous Airy Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to solve the inhomogeneous Airy equation? I have looked it up on the internet but I don't find this variant.

The equation I am trying to solve looks like this: $$y''-xy=N',$$

where $N(x)$ is the inhomogeneous (complex in general) term. The solution can be expressed as a function of the Airy functions $\operatorname{Ai}$ and $\operatorname{Bi}$.

Comment: what means $N'$?

Comment: A function of X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variation of parameters gives a solution in terms of integrals involving $N′$ and the solutions of the homogeneous equation:

$$ y(x) = - \pi Ai(x) \int Bi(x) N'(x)\; dx + \pi Bi(x) \int Ai(x) N'(x)\; dx + c_1 Ai(x) + c_2 Bi(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

From the calculus below :
$$y(x)=c_1\text{Ai}(x)+c_2\text{Bi}(x)-\text{Ai}(x) \int\left(\frac{1}{ (\text{Ai}(x))^2}\int (\text{Ai}(x))^2 \text{N}'(x)dx \right)dx$$

[image]

Note : if we look for another particular solution on the form $y_p=\text{Bi}(x)\text{F}(x)$, we obtain an apparently different, but in fact equivalent, form of solution. It doesn't matter the particular solution chosen since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary.